# Why does if statement not work and make my element disappear using display: none?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a tip calculator and I couldn't make the if statement in my function work it just skips to calculating.

```
function calculate() {
    var bill = parseInt(document.getElementById("bill").value);
    var tip = parseInt(document.getElementById("tip").value) * .01;
    var persons = parseInt(document.getElementById("persons").value);

    if (bill == "" || tip == "") {
        alert("Please enter value");
        return;
    };

    if (persons == "" || persons <= 1) {
        persons = 1;

        document.getElementById("perPerson").style.display = "none";

    } else {

    }

    let totalTipPer = (bill * tip) / persons;
    let totalPer = (bill + (tip * 100)) / persons;
    let totalTip = bill * tip;
    let total = bill + (tip * 100);

    totalTipPer = totalTipPer.toFixed(2);
    totalPer = totalPer.toFixed(2);
    total = total.toFixed(2);
    totalTip = totalTip.toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("total-tip/person").innerHTML = totalTipPer;
    document.getElementById("total-price/person").innerHTML = totalPer;
    document.getElementById("total-tip").innerHTML = totalTip;
    document.getElementById("total-price").innerHTML = total;
}

document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function () {
    calculate();
    document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block';
}
```

I expect the div encapsulating Tip Amount per person and total per person  and  to not appear when the input value of persons is empty.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: this is the html of the results container which shows the breakdown of tips and total amount of bill and how it is divided per person.

Comment: stack overflow wont let me copy and paste the whole html container. https://github.com/Otepiii/Tip-calculator/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `parseInt` returns 'An integer number parsed from the given string. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, `NaN` is returned.'
if you rpovide an empty value ('') it will return 
`NaN` which  is not equal to anything, even itself.

there are several ways to fix this:

1. check if it is a NaN with `Number.isNaN(var)`
2. use an intermediate value like `var personsValue` and check if it is equal to empty string ''.
3. use Hybrid suggested solution and assign a 0
   value for falsy value('', undefined, n

ull etc...)

Comment: That was exactly what was happening. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad i could help. And if it was helpful you can upvote or accept the answer, but if you don't that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `persons` becomes `NaN`, since if the value is left blank, `""` becomes `NaN` when it is run through `parseInt()`.

The way to fix this is by defaulting it to `0` if the field is left blank.

```
var persons = parseInt(document.getElementById("persons").value || 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

as others pointed out parseInt is returning NaN if the field is blank, but this will also happen if the user inputs $5.00 for example.

Here's one way to make sure the value can be converted to a number before doing so.

```
// This function determines if a JavaScript String can be converted into a number
function is_numeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function calculate() {
     // first put the input values into separate variables
    billValue = document.getElementById("bill").value;
    tipValue = document.getElementById("tip").value;
    personsValue = document.getElementById("persons").value;

    // use the is_numeric() function above to check if the values can be converted to numeric
    if (!is_numeric(billValue) || !is_numeric(tipValue)) {
        alert("Please enter values for bill and tip");
        return;
    }

// the rest of your code here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was tremendous. Thank you very much.